# How to reversely calculate predictors for given dependent variable with a random forest model?

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

Given a random forest model `y ~ x1 + x2`, is there a possibility to hand the model a value for `y` and get possible results of `x1` and `x2` back?

To give a short random example:

```
require(randomForest)
mydf <- data.frame(y =  c(1, 5, 6, 8, -1, -4), x1 = c(2, 8, 7, 10, 3, 0), x2 = c(18, 24, 26, 30, 15, 12))
myrf <- randomForest(y ~ ., data = mydf)
```

Is there a way to reverse calculate the predictors with the random forest model?

Answer (score 0):

No. Such functionality does not exist, and I cannot see why it would exist. You are trying to do something Random Forest is not designed to do. But if you wanted to, and I don't think you should, you could generate an N-D space, in this case for x1 and x2, which has all predictions and then subset the regions that are sufficiently close to the value of y.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: no in most cases.

Without going too much into the details, a random forest is more or less the average between several decision trees.
In most cases, it's not possible to reverse a decision tree. For instance in the following:

[image]

If the prediction is 4.5, your original data could be any value inferior to 10.5 (e.g. Alcohol level=0 and Alcohol level=3 would have 4.5 as predicted value).

The only way you would be able to reverse a tree would be if you happen to create a bijection between the cartesian product of your input data and your predicted value; but that would be quite seldom (and it would probably overfit)